# Proper morphisms maps closed subvarieties to closed subvarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In William Fulton Intersection theory:
"Let $f:X \to Y$ be a proper morphism of schemes of finite type over $K$. $V$ be an integral closed subscheme of $X$, then $f(V)=W$ is an integral closed subscheme of $Y$. There is an induced embedding of $R(W)$ in $R(V)$."
It's obvious that $W$ is closed an irreducible, hence there is a unique integral closed subscheme structure on $W$.

Does $f$ induce a (proper?) morphism from $V$ to $W$? If so, how? 
If not, how does $f$ induce an embedding of $R(W)$ in $R(V)$?

If $f:A \to B$ is a ring homomorphism and $I$ is an ideal of $A$ such that $J=f(I)$ is an ideal, then there is an induced morphism $f:A/I \to B/J$. But I have some difficulty generalizing this to schemes.